# Python dict to DataFrame Pandas - levels

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Few months ago  @Romain X. helped me a lot with this question:

[Python dict to DataFrame Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770359/python-dict-to-dataframe-pandas/32771114#32771114)

Now I´m trying to do the same with deeper levels, here is the example:

```
 {u'instruments': [{u'instrument': u'EUR_USD',
   u'interestRate': {u'EUR': {u'ask': 0.004, u'bid': 0},
    u'USD': {u'ask': 0.004, u'bid': 0}}}]}
```

Columns labels and values of my Data Frame should be *instrument, EUR_ask, EUR_bid, USD_ask, USD_bid.*

I tried this:

`pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df).join(pd.DataFrame.
from_dict(df['instruments'])).drop('instruments', axis=1)`

Thanks!

Comment: So, if you've tried something, can you show us what?

Comment: @Merlin . Is clear what I want to do now?.

Comment: No, you still havent shown what you have tried, SO is not a coding service.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried so many things but I´m sure that I´m very far away from the solution :-)

Comment: As a starting point I would suggest that you try to extract the data you are interested in and write those into a new dictionary with the desired column names. After that you could use that new dict to generate the dataframe. This might be sub-optimal form a performance point-of-view, but it gives you the capability to get an idea how to deal with such tasks by dividing it into minor subtasks you can accomplish already.

Comment: @Merlin Ok, I edited my post, you can see now my pathetic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)\
.join(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d['instruments']))\
.drop('instruments', axis=1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df.interestRate[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame.transpose(df2)
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2.columns.values[0] = 'instrument'

print (df2)

  instrument    ask  bid
0        EUR  0.004  0.0
1        USD  0.004  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jossie Calderon