# Not able to convert my dictionary to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this

```
{'community_0': 30,
'community_1': 29,
'community_2': 15,
'community_3': 16,
'community_4': 123,
'community_5': 9,
'community_6': 36,
'community_7': 71,
'community_8': 95,
'community_9': 21}
```

i want to convert it to a pandas dataframe. I tried `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='index')` but it gave me something else:

[image]

I referred to this post [Convert Python dict into a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe)
but it didn't help much.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So `pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=['Date', 'DateValue'])` not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dict to DataFrame Pandas - levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554706/python-dict-to-dataframe-pandas-levels)

Comment: actually no, giving me the same undesired result like the one before

Comment: I ran `pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()))` with `d` being the dictionary you gave, and it works on my side. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: it didn't work for me. I am using python 3.5

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I tried the methods suggested above. all giving me no result in column #2

Comment: I applied this. it is raising the following error: ValueError: malformed node or string: {'community_0': 30, 'community_1': 29, 'community_2': 15, 'community_3': 16, 'community_4': 123, 'community_5': 9, 'community_6': 36, 'community_7': 71, 'community_8': 95, 'community_9': 21}

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I've suggested an edit to include the dictionary as code. In the future, please do not post images of code, as they are impossible to copy. To learn more, please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can confirm @jezrael 's answer worked for me. You should display the output you get, and include the code you've tried to produce the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a `pd.Series` directly out of your dictionary, and then use the `.to_frame()` method to turn a `pd.Series` into a single-column DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'community_0': 30,
'community_1': 29,
'community_2': 15,
'community_3': 16,
'community_4': 123,
'community_5': 9,
'community_6': 36,
'community_7': 71,
'community_8': 95,
'community_9': 21}

pd.Series(d).to_frame()
```

returns:

```
            0
community_0 30
community_1 29
community_2 15
community_3 16
community_4 123
community_5 9
community_6 36
community_7 71
community_8 95
community_9 21
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what type of structure you want in Dataframe.

If you want to show keys in dict as rows value, then use:

-> pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(d)).reset_index()

If you want to show keys in dict as columns, then follow below steps:

1. First use your dictionary in a "List" like this:

   d = **[** {
   'community_0': 31,
   'community_1': 29
   'community_2': 15
   } **]**
2. Then use -> pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

Comment: Your "keys in dict as columns" case is exactly what benjibat suggested below, and OP already said it did not work for them

Comment: mine code will work. I've tested it. Reason for this is I've mentioned dictionary in a list "d= [{" but in the given problem it is only "d={". That makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.DataFrame([d])` will make it .

Comment: On my machine it creates a single-row dataframe, not a single column. What does it create on your machine? Note that OP (the Original Poster) asked for a single-column dataframe.

Comment: Yes I tried. You get a one raw DataFrame with all the values