# Pandas nested dict to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

I have a simple nested list like this:

```
allFrame= [{'statValues': {'kpi2': 2, 'kpi1': 1}, 'modelName': 'first'},{'statValues': {'kpi2': 4, 'kpi1': 2}, 'modelName': 'second'}, {'statValues': {'kpi2': 3, 'kpi1': 3}, 'modelName': 'third'}]
```

a `pd.DataFrame(allFrame)` or `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(allFrame)`both do not really work and only return [image: json]

### How can I instead receive the kpi_X as column-names?

I found [Python dict to DataFrame Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770359/python-dict-to-dataframe-pandas) doing something similar. However, I believe this operation should be simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to flatten those dicts first.

Apply a flattening function on the list first:

```
def flatten_dict(d, prefix='__'):
    def items():
        # A clojure for recursively extracting dict like values
        for key, value in d.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for sub_key, sub_value in flatten_dict(value).items():
                    # Key name should imply nested origin of the dict,
                    # so we use a default prefix of __ instead of _ or .
                    yield key + prefix + sub_key, sub_value
            else:
                yield key, value
    return dict(items())
```

Also note the use of orient=records, meaning each dict in the list is a line in the dataframe.

So:

```
l = list(map(flatten_dict, allFrame))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l, orient='records')
```

Comment: The mapping / flattening works fine. However, the conversion to DF is causing a problem: only recognize index or columns for orient. But after removing the option it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.DataFrame(list(allFrame.items()),columns=['modelName','statVlues'])
```

Comment: Please, Bonus Luo, include an explanation about why you think the answer should solve the issue. Thank you.