# Python:get data from nested dict to draw a bar

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, matplotlib

I'm trying to get data from a dict like this:

```
d= { 
'1992': 
{ 'j': 2048, 'f': 1290, 'm': 3221, 'a': 6994, 'ma': 2091, 'ju': 688, 'jl': 981, 'ag': 2389, 's': 3010, 'o': 13006, 'n': 10477, 'd': 6022 },
'1998': 
{ 'j': 1751, 'f': 1056, 'm': 2664, 'a': 3091, 'ma': 1088, 'ju': 1215, 'jl': 699, 'ag': 2108, 's': 1799, 'o': 4522, 'n': 7200, 'd': 5614 }}
```

and continue with this pattern:
 ('year(x)':{'month1':value(1),...month(n):value(n))}

and visualize them in an bar that has in the x axis the list of months, and in the y axis the year. I tried using the `Dataframe` solution from [Python dict to DataFrame Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770359/python-dict-to-dataframe-pandas) but I cannot apply to the graph. Matplotlib allows me to insert only one 'year':

```
plt.bar(range(len(d)), d.values(), fill=False)
```

so i guess Pandas 'Dataframe' is better. Is there a way to get these data in the same bar?

Comment: How does it work? Or need something else?

Comment: I don't think the question makes much sense. A histogram has some occurence/frequency/count on the y axis, but if you have "year" on the y axis and "month" on the xaxis, what is the data to be histogrammed?

Comment: jezrael 's response will clear your dubt @ImportanceOfBeingErnets. Data stored in the histogram is embedded in the bars size so I don't need numerical values to understand the graph. The format of the dict could give you a hint

Comment: The answer you got here does not plot a histogram of the data, but a bar plot of the values, where the values are on the y axis, not the year. Also it has no "unfilled stack-step". It may well be that you like the answer and it solves your problem, but it does not answer the question - which is not so much the fault of the answerer but the fault of the question, which is then completely off the problem.

Comment: Yes, the answer is not completely right, but it contains the aspect that i wanted. Furthermore, the example I made doesn't reflect exactly my own problem, but is a generic rapresentation of it. If I did some mistakes please tell me and I'll correct asap

Comment: The point is, according to the question you are looking for something that the answer does not provide; however you accepted the answer. So there are two options. Either you edit the question to ask for exactly what the answer provides, or you edit the question to ask for the initial problem but make it clearer, and unaccept the answer. I would guess the first option is the easier one. But in any case if the question stays as it is, people searching for a solution to plot an unfilled stacked histogram from a dictionary will be extremely annoyed not to find the solution here in the future.

Comment: "But in any case if the question stays as it is, people searching for a solution to plot an unfilled stacked histogram from a dictionary will be extremely annoyed not to find the solution here in the future"
You are right, revised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.plot.bar()
```

If want also set order of `months`:

```
names = ['j', 'f', 'm', 'a', 'ma','ju', 'jl', 'ag', 's',  'o', 'n', 'd']
df = pd.DataFrame(d).reindex(names)
```

---

```
print (df)
     1992  1998
j    2048  1751
f    1290  1056
m    3221  2664
a    6994  3091
ma   2091  1088
ju    688  1215
jl    981   699
ag   2389  2108
s    3010  1799
o   13006  4522
n   10477  7200
d    6022  5614
```

[image: graph]